# I'm having a problem dragging and dropping an object in VR using Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm trying to drag and drop a 3d object. I got it working in the editor using the mouse, however whenever I try to get it to work in VR, it follows the camera instead of the LineRenderer. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.UI;

public class XRDragDrop : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler
{
    private Vector3 mOffset;
    private float mZCoord;
    [SerializeField]
    private LineRenderer leftLineRenderer;
    [SerializeField]
    private LineRenderer rightLineRenderer;
    
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = GetReticleWorldPos() + mOffset;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(eventData.currentInputModule);
        mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position).z;
        mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - GetReticleWorldPos();
    }
    private Vector3 GetReticleWorldPos()
    {
        // Vector3 reticlePoint = rightLineRenderer.GetPosition(1);
        Vector3 reticlePoint = Input.mousePosition;
        reticlePoint.z = mZCoord;
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(reticlePoint);
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag");
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
    }
}
```

I've tried getting the position of the reticle using the commented out code, but it gives the exact same result as just getting the mouse position. Does anyone have any idea why the object would be following the Camera instead of the LineRenderer?

Comment: Well the `GetReticleWorldPos()` uses `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(reticlePoint)` so the resulting position always depends on the `Camera.main` position and orientation

Comment: Ah I see, do you have any idea how I would go about changing it so it works for a 3d environment? As in the editor when the camera was static, the object would follow the object fine, whereas in vr it doesn't follow it at all even if I try to keep the camera still.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm a complete idiot as since I was able to get the pointer position using rightLineRenderer.GetPosition(1), I didn't even need to convert it using ScreenToWorldPoint as it already was a world position. However, I managed to do what I wanted in a much simpler way that requires way less code using just the PointerEventData. Here is what I did:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class XRDragDrop : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler
{
    private Vector3 mOffset;
    
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition + mOffset;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
    }
}
```